Why does TypeScript not accept 16 as number?
I've used the following type (see this answer for implementation details):
type FixedSizeArray<N extends number, T> = {
  length: N
} & ReadonlyArray<T>

But then TS doesn't accept:
someProp: Array.from({ length: 16 }).map(() => '')

where someProp expects FixedSizeArray<16, string>.
I either have to cast it or write '' 16 times. The actual error thrown being:
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'FixedSizeArray<16, string>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '{ length: 16; }'.
    Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '16'.ts(2322)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

It does accept 16 as a number. It doesn't accept any number as 16 (because only one number, 16, is both number and 16). Array.from({ length: 16 }) doesn't create a FixedSizeArray, just a regular one.

But I'm not passing any number as 16. I'm passing 16. Should I not expect it to work?

Wait, you're saying I should write it as: Array.from({ length: 16 as 16 }).map(() => '')? That doesn't work, either, besides being a bit silly.

Type 'number' is not assignable to type '16'.ts(2322) - Array.from({ length: 16 }).map(() => '') creates Array<string>, whose length is just a number. So it's not a FixedSizeArray<16, string>, for the reason the error tells you. For this to work you'd also have to override from itself (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4b12d82b6bb4c8e2ad7df3219ae7282e360e62f9/src/lib/es2015.iterable.d.ts#L78-L92) and map.

Ok, is there a way to make the syntax more flexible, so TS actually checks the length of the array and each element's type in usage, so we don't have to write '' 1000 times for a FixedSizeArray<1000, string>? Without casting, I mean, which is wrong. It's just telling TS: "sit down and shut up, I'm smarter than you, and you're useless in this case". Casting kind of defeats the purpose of using TS, right?

I don't know what you mean by "make the syntax more flexible" - you can't change the syntax of the language, no. If by "casting" you mean type assertions then they're for exactly the cases when you know more than the type system does. Fundamentally you're not creating an array of fixed length, though (and having length: 16 has no impact on the values at indexes before or after 15, whether or not you allow unchecked index access).

Yeah, by "casting" I meant "type assertion". My knowledge of TS is limited.

If you think Array.from should already work this way, then this answer is what you want: to merge in your own call signature.  This is "equivalent" to a type assertion to the extent that TS cannot check it. But TS already does not "check" that Array.from is implemented so that it produces an array. It's a TS library type definition for native JS stuff, so those are always just declared and not checked. Aside: FixedSizeArray is a poor substitute for tuples.

@jcalz, could you link a better alternative to declare a fixed size array of type T? I might not understand tuples correctly, but [string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string] is not what I want. Imagine 16 is 1k. How do I declare that?

There are definitions that will evaluate to a tuple from a numeric literal which I can maybe link when I get to a real computer. But 1000 for a fixed length array is quite big; what’s the use case for these arrays? Is it that TS detects indexing errors? Or just that you don’t cross-assign them?

@jcalz, I don't have a use case. I used it to answer someone's question (linked above), (and they used tuple, btw). From my POV, 3 is a large enough number to not have to write it down for each element (nevermind 16) and I was expecting TS to accommodate a syntax in which the element type is only written once. It's a theoretical question: How do I use TS to check that an array has a declared length (large) and each element has a declared type? Does that exceed TS's current syntax capabilities? Also, why is the substitute "poor"?

I don't disagree with your opinion. But I would like to understand it and some facts would help in that regard.

See ms/TS#26223 and this version (which allows truly huge tuples, but most people don't need them; there are simpler TupleOf implementations). Without a use case then I suppose I have no basis by which to say "poor" or not. The usual use case for tuples is to be able to index into them by valid indices only and have TS know what is there. So you wouldn't access x[100] on a length-16 tuple. There's also spread/destructuring, which TS understand for tuples. Having {length: 16} doesn't work that way.

But if the use case is just "answer someone else's question" then I suppose it's that questioner's use cases we care about? I'm not inclined to do too much navigating here.

Array.length is a runtime property with type number. At runtime it could be any number, not necessarily 16 as expected by FixedSizeArray<16, string>.length. This is what the error message is trying to say.
This is the behavior of Array.length in the sense that it is designed that at runtime its length could be anything. Fitting it into a FixedSizeArray is an attempt to remove this flexibility, in which case you may need to just use a cast when you can guarantee you know better than the compiler.
For example using a helper function like,
function createFixedSizeArray<N extends number, T>(length: N, value: T): FixedSizeArray<N, T> {
  return Array.from({ length }).map(() => value) as FixedSizeArray<N, T>;
}

...

const someProp = createFixedSizeArray(16, '');


Casting kind of defeats the purpose of using TS, right?

I agree with this instinct, but there are these kinds of times when you have to force the compiler to assume behavior, which is why these kinds of syntax exist.

You only moved the casting into a function. I'm looking for a way which doesn't require casting. Casting defeats the purpose of using TypeScript, IMHO.

Probably better to have a valueFactory, otherwise you'd get into problems with arrays of mutable objects.

Good point @jonrsharpe; actually I think I'd prefer to just return the array unmapped and let callers populate as they wish. I'll leave the answer as a quick n dirty way to demonstrate the concept but edits welcome

Why the error?
For any n: number the expression Array.from({ length: n }) creates a value of type { length: number }. You are then trying to assign it to the property typed { length: 16 }. Since there is no guarantee that the number is actually 16, you get the error.
So, the very question is incorrect. It is not trying to treat 16 as a number, it is trying to treat an unknown number as 16, which is obviously an error.
How do I fix it?
At some point, you'll have to give certain information to TypeScript compiler (either by casting or otherwize) that it can't infer on its own.
You can always define a custom function that'd do the casting for you, it shouldn't be too hard. Alternatively, you can instruct the Array.from function itself to infer the length automatically whenever possible:
declare global {
  interface ArrayConstructor {
    from<Item, Length>(arrayLike: { [index: number]: Item; length: Length }): Item[] & { length: Length }
  }
}

Array.from({ length: 42 }).length // <-- typed as `number`

Array.from({ length: 42 as const }).length // <-- typed as `42`

Try it.

Adding that typing to Array.from gives you a fixed size array, but map then discards the length. You'd have to re-type a large portion of Array's members

That's something you'd have to do regardless of the approach, since FixedSizeArray is only a type alias.
